# Sails.js/Waterline association during create

Tags: sails.js

I have a signup-form who POST to a UserController connected to a User model. A user belongs to an Organization. I want a new Organization row to be created during signup and a proper relation being setup to the user just being created. Is this possible with Sails/Waterline in the create step of a user?

**signup.ejs**

```
<h1>Signup</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/organization/users/">
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="text" name="organizationName">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**User.js (model)**

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        email: {
            type: 'email',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: 'string',
            minLength: 6,
            required: true
        },
        organization: {
          model: 'organization'
        }
    }
};
```

**UserController.js**

```
module.exports = {
  create: function (req, res) {
    var options = {
      name: req.param('email'),
      password: req.param('password')
    };

    User.create(options).exec(function(err, user) {
      return res.redirect("/users");
    });

  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is more appropriate  *Is this possible with waterline...* since what you are asking is more concerned with what waterline can do. Check out the [waterline documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks%22Lifecycle%20Callback%20Documentation%22).

You can create a new record of the Organization if the name does not exist and assign the id to user.organization.

**create action**

```
  create: function (req, res) {
    var options = {
      name: req.param('email'),
      password: req.param('password')
    };

    Organization.findOrCreate({name: req.param('organization')})
      .exec(function(err,org){
        options.organization = org.id;
        User.create(options).exec(function(err, user) {
          return res.redirect("/users");
        });
      });
  }
```

But if you want to create a new record each time you create a new user, you can do this:

**create action**

```
create: function (req, res) {
    var options = {
      name: req.param('email'),
      password: req.param('password'),
      organization: {
        name: req.param("organization")
      }
    };

    User.create(options).exec(function(err, user) {
      return res.redirect("/users");
    });
  }
```

Waterline would create a new organization **each time** a user is created.

**Note:**

1) findOrCreate is not atomic so do not use it when expected high concurrency since it is implemented by a find and, if nothing is found, a create.

2) I'm not sure if the behavior of *Model.create* is documented, but you can find it when using .add() [with a new record](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/associations/many-to-many.md) of a populated attribute.

Comment: You did not only provide a excellent answer, but also learned me that Waterline will create records in associated table just by providing the key in the request. Your help is truly appreciated. PS, I will update the question to reflect your comment on the subject.